# Output just the background color, just an image or both together

Tags: php

On my template I have a field where the user(s) can choose and select a background for their site.

[image]

This is called from the ID `background-one` in an array.

My question is, how would I be able to output this into the head section of my CSS correctly if the users are only given the following options:

1) The choice of just a background color

> background: #990000;

2) The choice of just a background image

> background: url(../images/example.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll;

3) Or the choice of a background color and an image

> background: #990000 url(../images/example.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll;

---

This is my current snippet of code to output the script into the css head section:

```
<?php $background = of_get_option('background-one'); {  
    if ($background['color'] || $background['image']) {
        echo 'body {
        background: ' . $background['color'] . ' url(' . $background['image']. ') ' .$background['repeat']. ' ' .$background['position']. ' ' .$background['attachment']. ';';
    }

    else if ($background['color']) {  
        echo 'body {
        background: ' . $background['color']. ';';
    }

    else if ($background['image']) {
        echo 'body {
        background: ' . 'url(' . $background['image']. ') ' .$background['repeat']. ' ' .$background['position']. ' ' .$background['attachment']. ';';
    };
}
?>
```

But with that, the results are:

1) The choice of just a background color

> background: #990000 url() no-repeat top left scroll;

2) The choice of just a background image

> background: url(../images/example.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll;

3) Or the choice of a background color and an image

> background: #990000 url(../images/example.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll;

As I'm fairly new to writing PHP, how would I re-work my snippet above to get the results I'm after?

Comment: The  problem is that bcakground-one can only be 1 value. It can either be color OR background, but not both. Therefore, there is no way to do both unless you make a `both` value for background-one.

Comment: How would I go about creating a `both` value, as PHP is not my forte'

Comment: Ah the way below will work as well. I thought of it as well, but I forgot it was PHP ^.^

Comment: No worries, thanks for everything @MrXenotype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following:

```
if ($background['color'] || $background['image']) {
```

To this:

```
if ($background['color'] && $background['image']) {
```

The reason your snippet doesn't work like you want it to is because "||" equals "OR", which means that if either "$background['color']" or if "$background['image']" is set, the if-statement will apply.

Using "&&" instead, which in English means "AND", would make the if-statement only apply if both "color" and "image" are set.

Comment: Thank you @Nanashi Dri, I had a look into this previously but search engines don't always return the best results on symbols and their usage.  The && works a treat!

Comment: Sometimes it's good to rephrase your queries when you make a search on a search-engine. Using "And Or PHP" instead of "&& || php" will most likely return valuable results. You're welcome though, :)